# Python Machine Learning

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to predict my server load however I am getting a below 10% accuracy. I am using Linear Regression to predict the data, can anyhow one help me out?

**ps, the csv file contain date and time so i convert both to integer. Not sure am i doing it right**

These are my Codes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import mpl_toolkits
import imp
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn import preprocessing

data = pd.read_csv(".....\\Machine_Learning_Serious\\Server_Prediction\\testing_server.csv")
describe = data.describe()

data_cleanup = {"Timestamp":{'AM': 0, 'PM': 1},
    "Function":{'ccpl_db01': 0, 'ccpl_fin01': 1, 'ccpl_web01': 2},
    "Type": {'% Disk Time': 0, 'CPU Load': 1, 'DiskFree%_C:': 2, 'DiskFree%_D:': 3, 'DiskFree%_E:': 4, 'FreeMemory': 5, 'IIS Current Connections': 6, 'Processor Queue Length': 7, 'SQL_Buffer cache hit ratio': 8, 'SQL_User Connections': 9}}
data.replace(data_cleanup,inplace = True)
final_data = data.head()
#print(final_data)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression()
labels = data['Data']
train1 = data.drop(['Data'], axis = 1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import ensemble
x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(train1, labels, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 2)
#clf = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators= 400 , max_depth = 5,min_samples_split = 2, learning_rate = 0.1,loss='ls')
fitting = reg.fit(x_train,y_train)
score = reg.score(x_test,y_test)
```

- The main objective is to predict the correct load but right now I am way too off.

Comment: Maybe there simply is no *linear* connection between your data and the label?

Comment: @ChristianKönig, hmmm...how do i know if there is a linear connection or no linear connection? Is there anyway to check it out?

Comment: Well, that's the whole point of machine learning, isn't it? To find connections in your data. If there was an easy way to check, why would you do a linear regression?

Comment: @ChristianKönig, uh...i get it now...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe do some Exploratory data analysis first to see if you can figure out a pattern between your target variable and features?

It would also be good to extract some features from your date/time variables rather than using them as integers (like weekday_or_not, seasons etc.)

You can also try transforming your features (log, sqrt) to see if the score improves.

I would also suggest that you try a simple randomforest/xgboost model to check how that performs against the linear regression model